# CurrentAppSimulator ignored on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-mobile

When debugging a UWP app on a PC, we use  `CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation` returns the contents of `WindowsStoreProxy.xml`, so we can test different cases. When connecting a Windows 10 Mobile phone - `WindowsStoreProxy.xml` is ignored.

Why / What's the solution?

Comment: You can add `WindowsStoreProxy.xml` to your solution and load it at run time. I remember I added the File to my solution and then loaded it during run time. Check `ReloadSimulatorAsync` from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh779766)

Comment: I can post my code as an answer if you want me to.

Comment: @AVKNaidu Thanks. Code not necessary. You can simply post your comment as answer. This looks like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `WindowsStoreProxy.xml` to your solution and load it at run time. I remember I added the File to my solution and then loaded it during run time. Check `ReloadSimulatorAsync` from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh779766)

---

**Update:** For anyone who wants to know how to do this, Below is the code.

Add this to your `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
public static async Task TestSimulator()
{
    var proxyFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"WindowsStoreProxy.xml");
    await CurrentAppSimulator.ReloadSimulatorAsync(proxyFile);
}
```

and Call this method on `OnNavigatedTo`

```
await MainPage.TestSimulator();
```

**Note:** For some reason, this code did not work for me when i added this in `App.xaml.cs` so i used it in `MainPage.xaml.cs`